# toBeCalled returns false even though the mock function is being called

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I'm testing a koa server.
The `verifyRequest' is a middleware which calls http request internally, so I want to mock the function and test that the function is called properly.

The first time I run the mock function, `toBeCalled` returns true as expected.
However, after executing `mockClear`, `toBeCalled` returns false, even though the mock function is executed (please see the logs below).

Can anyone explain the curious behavior? And please let me know how I can run mock clear correctly.

```js
// server.test.ts

import {verifyRequest} from '../middlewares/verifyRequest';
import {mocked} from 'jest-mock';
import {agent} from './lib/agent';

jest.mock('../middlewares/verifyRequest', () => {
  return {
    verifyRequest: jest.fn().mockImplementation(
      (): Middleware<DefaultState, Context, any> => {
        return async function (_ctx, next) {
          console.log('mocked verifyRequest is called!');
          await next();
        };
      }
    ),
  };
});

afterEach(() => {
  mocked(verifyRequest).mockClear();
});

it('test-one', async () => {
  await agent.get('/'); // verifyRequest will be called as a middleware
  console.log('test-one', mocked(verifyRequest).mock);
  expect(verifyRequest).toBeCalled();
});
it('test-two', async () => {
  await agent.get('/');
  console.log('test-two', mocked(verifyRequest).mock);
  expect(verifyRequest).toBeCalled();
});
```

```js
// ../middlewares/verifyRequest
import compose from 'koa-compose';
import {Context, DefaultState, Middleware} from 'koa';

export function verifyRequest(): Middleware<DefaultState, Context, any> {
  return compose([
    ...myMiddlwares
  ]);
}
```

```
    console.log
      mocked verifyRequest is called!

    console.log
      test-one {
        calls: [ [ [Object] ], [ [Object] ], [ [Object] ], [ [Object] ] ],
        instances: [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ],
        invocationCallOrder: [ 5, 6, 9, 10 ],
        results: [
          { type: 'return', value: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] },
          { type: 'return', value: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] },
          { type: 'return', value: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] },
          { type: 'return', value: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)] }
        ]
      }

    console.log
      mocked verifyRequest is called!

    console.log
      test-two { calls: [], instances: [], invocationCallOrder: [], results: [] }
```

```
versions
"jest": "^27.4.7",
"jest-mock": "^27.4.6",
"ts-jest": "^27.1.3",
```